# PHP container log redirection to docker logs

Tags: php, docker, logging, dockerfile, php-7.1

I am working to create a LEMP stack-based dockerized environment in AWS ECS using docker-compose. My `php7.1-fpm` and `nginx` containers are interconnected and working fine as expected.

I have redirected my Nginx logs to docker logs successfully. I would like to do the same for the PHP container based on this [link](https://dev.to/mtk3d/how-to-configure-php-logs-for-docker-2384). Logs redirection is not working as expected. As I verified, found old blogs with no use of it. There is no clear workaround for redirecting php-fpm logs to docker logs(stdout/stderr). Can anyone please help me with this?

Any information would be appreciated.

Official Docker image - php-fpm-7.1

Composer version - 1.10.26

Laravel/framework - 5.5.48